# Liferay: How to fetch the first 3 items from an asset publisher?

Tags: liferay, assets, publisher

In Liferay I have used the asset publisher to publish news on my news page. I want to fetch the 3 top news from the page and embed it into another page. How can I do this? The page URL containing the news links looks like the following:

```
Liferay.Widget({ url: 'http://test.com/testnews/101_INSTANCE_f22'});
```

Liferay itself has a property where one can share an asset publsiher instance any where else on a site, but that is not exactly what I want. So any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Here is the solution with jQuery:

```
 $.get('http://test.com/news/', function(data) {
      var top3links = $(data).find('a:lt(3)');
      $('#top3').html(top3links); // });
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want only links then you can set display style 'title-list' (this will take you to the article on the main news page). 
if you want to open the link in another page, change asset link behavior to 'View in a specific portlet'.
You can change the look of asset publisher to whatever design you want. follow the path look & feel --> advanced styling --> Copy the portlet id. Now by using mozilla firefox pick the class,tags,etc. and write your css code. This will override the basic design. E.g.

```
#p_p_id_101_INSTANCE_8f5JPIxv8ml0_ .asset-abstract {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vaibu. I have tried that as well actually before resorting to jQuery. The problem is that if I use display style 'title-list', when click a link the content is displayed in the same page, inside the 25% wide asset publisher, rather than taking me to the page where the original news article is. If I use 'View in a specific portlet' style, then the (3) links become inactive, which I find weird. I expected this to open a new window for the link content. On the other side, I am now happy with the jQuery solution. Has been working perfectly:)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why you don't want to configure another AssetPublisher on the second page? You can just use the identical configuration, but limit the number of results shown to 3 - done.

Comment: Because on this page where I want to embed the top three news I only want the links. So when you click the links it would take you to the article on the main news page. One problem is that the asset publisher would open the link in the same page which is only a small window; the second problem is that I can't change the look of the asset publisher which looks different from the rest of the pae, and this is not nice.